# Too many connections when accessing database from AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, micronaut

I'm developing a Lambda which will copy some S3 objects around and do some updates to a database.

The input comes from a SQS queue and will eventually amount to a few millions.

```
Bean definition [io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Failed to initialize pool: Could not connect to address=(host=terraform-2020112813573819550000000d.cljpfhswxbks.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=65) Too many connections: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Failed to initialize pool: Could not connect to address=(host=terraform-2020112813573819550000000d.cljpfhswxbks.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=65) Too many connections
...
```

My data source (application.yml)

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
    username: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    maximum-pool-size: 50
    max-lifetime: 5000        # milliseconds
    connection-timeout: 5000  # milliseconds
```

When I test with just few items (less than 10) on the queue I get "too many connections". How can I get Micronaut to close the connections, open less or how to go about this?

I'm using JPA and the Hikari connection pool. I'll happily post my code but I don't think it's relevant.

I'm using terraform to create my RDS instance

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "rds" {
  name = "mydatabase"
  allocated_storage = 10
  engine = var.database_engine
  engine_version = var.database_engine_version
  instance_class = "db.t2.micro"
  username = "someUserName"
  password = random_password.password.result
  skip_final_snapshot = true
  apply_immediately = true

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.rds.id]
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.db.name

  parameter_group_name = aws_db_parameter_group.db.name
}

resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "db" {
  name = "rds-pg"
  family = "mariadb10.5"

  parameter {
    name = "max_connections"
    value = "80"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what the default value is for "max_connections" but 80 should be about the maximum for a 1GB instance.

Comment: oh thats tricky :D but its not a micronaut related question ;-) its about the jdbc pool (hikari) in your case or the database driver below .. we had similar effects with postgresql do you need a max-pool-size of 50 .. my first idea is to reduce that to 20 e.g

Comment: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

Comment: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Comment: Be aware of [Amazon RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/) though it currently does not support MariaDB.